# How to select binary data from postgres column

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am.programming an.application in which i am selecting data from postgres database and table name cards.

In.cards we have many columns but two.columns are bytea datatype. It has a blob saved one.column is named as tpl and other is photo but when i select data and fill datatable through dataAdapter the datable shows theese two column values as System.Byte[] and when i insert it in my master database it.insert it as System.Byte[] it is loosing.the binary data which is in the column. I have to.syncrhonize local server tables to master server . We have different gates in our company where passes are issued and.then.they are synchrinized to a central sever ..

I hope you people get my point please help

Databae is postgresql 8.2
Apllication is on.c#

Comment: "I have to synchronize local server tables to master server." — why not use replication. (Also, upgrade that Postgres install. That version is no longer maintained for security.)

Comment: Thanx for your reply but you must know that company doesnot want to switch to other version they ate very dumb.if you have a good suggestion for replication.let me.know we have 10 gates each has local server running and it my sync application.sync data to central and some time the local server sync from master to insert and update the local so its a two way syncrhonize ...

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/high-availability.html

Comment: Which one should i adopt

Comment: PostgreSQL *8.2* ? Seriously? Are you using nPgSQL? Something else?

Comment: @ShakoorAlam Your only choice on 8.2 is PITR, maybe warm standby. I strongly recommend upgrading to 9.2 or 9.3 and using synchronous streaming replication instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger I would like to tell you that we have 10 Gates every gate has a local server where the application is issuing Gate Passing and inserting it in the local postgres Database .with the same schema as the master server So mean to say we have 10 Local Databases no Failover issue will arise there because those local databases are the main server for the application at that time. But there is a central Server on a network where all the gates synchronize data and the local servers also fetch data from master server. so that people use barcode cards to use the turnstiles.

Comment: OK, so you want to merge data from satellite DBs. That's a good job for Bucardo, or for Londiste from Skytools. Both should work even on 8.2.

Comment: I guess Bucardo runs on Linux? isn't it  Let me know if theres is any help available for windows ?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on a db system before where it used dblink connections for controlling the data transfer between postgres servers of different versions. This included transferring of bytea data and maintaining the data type. Dblink connections are a little restrictive and I can't speak for connection time overheads however they serve their purpose well for data transfer.

On the main server the data was pulled in from the satellites:

```
INSERT INTO main_table
SELECT * FROM dblink("connect_string", ''SELECT tpl, photo FROM satellite_table;'')
AS data(tpl bytea, photo bytea);
```

This allows you to specify the incoming data types specifically. Not sure if this helps but I've seen this working fine on an 8.3 db. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/contrib-dblink.html