# How to get Bytea Data in string from Postgres Database

Tags: c#, postgresql

Is there a way to get the actual encoded string saved in the Database of column with `DataType Bytea`. Because when the record is fetched in `C#` it returns as `System.Byte[]` which I don't want. I want the data which is saved in that column

`E'\\\142\\\247\\\` and so on till the data ends.

I will appreciate your support

When I am querying the data through

```
SELECT tpl::TEXT from Cards where ecode="xyz";
```

I get the following error

> Error: Cannot cast type bytea to text
>   Line1: Select tpl::TEXT from cards

Thank you

Like this

[image: Normal query]

[image]

As you see that the Bytea column is showing `System.Byte[]` which was overwritten by my application because the code in C# stores the data in the `DataTable` column as `System.Byte[]` while updating the data I didn't decode it and update it .

I am using Navicat premium when I query data it shows me the result when I right click on the grid result and copy as insert statement it shows me two result for different rows

like this

```
INSERT INTO "public"."cards" ("ecode", "tpl") VALUES ('4210149888659', E'System.Byte[]');

INSERT INTO "public"."cards" ("ecode", "tpl") VALUES('3650257637661',E '\\247\\377\\001\\021\\340\\000\\230\\000\\002U\\000e\\000\\362\\000\\002-\\000\\253\\000p\\000\\002\\207\\000~\\000g\\000\\002\\215\\000{\\000\\317\\000\\002\\334\\000h\\000\\222\\000\\001|\\000\\004\\001U\\000\\002\\202\\000K\\000\\201\\000\\001\\000\\000\\204\\000\\241\\000\\001w\\000\\213\\000\\305\\000\\002\\021\\000V\\000\\237\\000\\002L\\001=\\001\\364\\000\\001X\\001"\\001\\313\\000\\002J\\000\\010\\001\\324\\000\\001\\370\\000\\037\\001J\\000\\002;\\0017\\000\\202\\000\\002\\300\\000\\317\\0007\\000\\002\\215\\000[\\000\\004\\011\\017\\007\\012\\005\\015\\014\\006\\016\\012\\007\\010\\005\\005\\007\\011\\010\\001\\004\\012\\017\\002\\003\\010\\012\\004\\010\\005\\003\\013\\014\\005\\017\\007\\003\\010\\003\\001\\011\\004\\012\\006\\020\\011\\005\\013\\015\\010\\002\\004\\005\\010\\007\\011\\012\\000\\002\\002\\020\\012\\003\\015\\000\\005\\002\\017\\003\\000\\006\\016\\020\\010\\017\\014\\000\\001\\012\\001\\010\\011\\002\\004\\007\\010\\000\\002\\006\\011\\007\\003\\020\\011\\003\\001\\005\\011\\000\\007\\002\\012\\002\\000\\020\\000\\016\\004\\017\\004\\003\\011\\017\\000\\003\\004\\000\\001\\007\\017\\002\\001\\017\\014\\006\\002\\016\\015\\011\\015\\006\\014\\016\\010\\020\\013\\000\\003\\006\\015\\002\\005\\020\\015\\016\\015\\004\\001\\003\\015\\010\\010\\006\\014\\002\\007\\020\\014\\011\\001\\000\\014\\010\\003\\016\\001\\015\\017\\020\\013\\006\\013\\016\\013\\011\\001\\014\\013\\004\\013\\002\\013\\001\\000'
);
```

Comment: do you want to convert byte array to string?

Comment: How is this different to your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19914761/398670 ?

Comment: I am trying to explore the possibilities if this can be done easily then I guess I wont be needing any of the Bucardo and other stuff because I have the application written and I am just getting the issue with the bytea data thats all . I hope you can help me

Comment: I hope you can assist me as your a professional in working with PostGres

Comment: @SATSON yes I want to convert byte array to string .. because the way it was coded in was through Griaule SDK for Thumb impressions.

Comment: @SATSON when I fetch it in DataTable it doesn't show as the string data which is stroed in bytea

Comment: [Read](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html) This. Its May be use full for you

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert it because PostgreSQL can't guarantee it can be converted safely.  The best you can do is to convert the escaped form into a string and that's not what you probably want.  Keep in mind that since bytea is binary data there is no way that PostgreSQL can be sure that the string that comes out will be legit.  You could have embedded nulls in a UTF-8 string, for example, which could cause some fun with buffer overruns if you aren't careful.

This is the sort of thing that should be done in the client-side and you should assume that the data is binary, and not necessarily a valid string.  If you want to store strings, store text fields, not bytea.